# how to can upload a remote file with curl

Tags: php, file, curl

I'd like to know that I'm doing wrong in the following script in `PHP`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    $url = "http://www0.xup.in/exec/xupload.php?uid=&key=";
    $user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0";
    $referer = "http://www.xup.in/";
    if(isset($_FILES['f1'])){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['f1']['tmp_name'],"files/".$_FILES['f1']['name']);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("name"=>"F1","filename"=>"@"."files/".$_FILES['f1']['name']));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        //unlink("files/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
        echo $result;
    }else{
        echo '
            <form action="upload_curl.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="f1">Filename:</label>
                <input type="file" name="f1" id="f1"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>

        ';  
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It spends more that I try it gives me no results when it should, all I want is to upload a local image to that website using `curl` and show the result, but it shows blank instead and I do not know why, I thought my logic was good, I hope someone can shed some light and tell me what's wrong, greetings and thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set the URL to make the curl call to, either use curl_setopt() to do that, or pass it as the first parameter curl_init().  In your case: `curl_init($url);`

Lastly, you should be checking `curl_error($ch)` for errors and handling them (Plus it might help tell you whats wrong with your code when developing it).